# Помогите составить запрос к api

Tags: node.js, api, axios

Задача создать конвертер валют.
Информация о ценах и валютах берётся из api вот запрос(https://currate.ru/api/?get=rates&pairs=USDRUB,EURRUB&key=763cfb0fa49f7c16319810bbf106680d), перепробовал около 20 вариаций запросов, в том числе ajax(раз тут get(простой запрос), то думал, что jsonp сработает, но у меня не вышло), fetch и главное axios, думаю я неправильно параметры в своих запросах указывал, потому что раз за разом мне выпадает запрет от CORS, буду благодарен любой помощи

```js
axios
 .get('https://currate.ru/api/?get=rates&pairs=USDRUB,EURRUB&key=763cfb0fa49f7c16319810bbf106680d')
 .then(response => (console.log(response.data)));
```

Смог составить работающий запрос, но он отрабатывает только к данному api и, так как там платные тарифы, он не очень подходит, но если ничего не останется, то и его использую...

```js
const getPrices = (convertFrom, convertTo) => {
  try {//http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=e51025cf18fbbc92b1211172d722d1ef&currencies="+ convertTo +"&source="+ convertFrom +"&format=1
    //console.log(convertFrom);
    return axios.get('http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=515ab4b259053480b6f00bc6961bb954');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

const conversion = async (convertFrom, convertTo) => {
  const prices = getPrices(convertFrom, convertTo)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      //return response;
      //$("#convert-from input").val(response.data.rates.AED);
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
   })
}

conversion('USD', 'RUB');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нода и CORS? Точно нода? Точно CORS?

Comment: @Alexey Ten Ну, запрос отправляется и ajax, и axios, а axios-пакет npm, думаю неправильно к ноде относить, но я не уверен к чему тогда надо) Я добавил скрин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что браузер запрещает делать кросс-доменные запросы в целях безопасности. 
За это отвечает заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, который возвращается в ответе, там должны быть прописаны домены с которых можно делать запросы к сервису, либо `*`  - для всех доменов. Из-за этого в вашем приложение происходит ошибка - браузер запрещает посылать запрос к таким сервисам.

Решение: 
Нужно создать простенький бекенд на который будет идти запрос из приложения, а бекенд будет отправлять запрос к сервису-конвертеру и затем возвращать результат приложению-клиенту.

Можно даже просто проксировать запрос, пример проксирования запроса - [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/). 
Чтоб посмотреть как это работает можно использовать уже поднятую версию такого сервиса, достаточно перед доменом дописать `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`, например `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://currate.ru/api/?get=rates&pairs=USDRUB,EURRUB&key=blablabla` - в таком запросе не будет CORS-ошибки.

[Подробнее про CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: Благодарю! Находил решение с прокси, но пробовать не стал, ибо думал, что запрос идёт с бека, а мне нужно было с фронта, можно было, конечно, и с бека делать, но тогда пришлось бы бд подрубать и крон настраивать дабы можно было при кликах запросы делать